# How to develop an extension for a simple form post and post back?

Tags: plugins, widgets, forms

I need to develop a plugin/widget or any kind of extension for WordPress that is a like a static page and is like a Form. In this page I have a form with some input fields that is submitted to server.

By submitting to server I mean I want a piece of code exists that gets Form's data, process it with help of some external web services, get response from that external web services and then creates and send backs response to the page I'm willing to develop.

What should I do? I must go with a special kind of plugins? Any directions?

Please consider I'm not going to use any data or API from WordPress itself.

I'm a ASP.NET MVC developer and have no practice with PHP practically.

Comment: If you are not going to use any WordPress API or data, why are you asking in WordPress StackExchange? Do it as you normally would do in PHP. Also, asking to recommend a third party plugin, library or extension is, in general, off-topic here. Please, read the [help center](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help) and [what topics you can ask about](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @cybmeta I edited the caption to show I'm searching for a way no a tool so hope it is not off-topic anymore. What I want from WordPress is that my page is integrated with it and seems same with all of the site.

Comment: *I'm a ASP.NET MVC developer and have no practice with PHP practically.* - Pardon me *I'm not a builder, but I'm gonna build a house* is a lame excuse. Let's learn some building first, and then let's try to build a house. It's a generic PHP question, where using another server for form data processing needs an API from that server. Let's learn some PHP first.

Comment: @MayeenulIslam, Actually I know how to build a house in ASP.NET I just wanted a hint to do same in PHP. I just need to develop a `pluging` that have `form` processing functionality. In server side I'm going to call another `REST` services.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the easiest way is adding the form via the [Shortcode API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API). The code would look like this:

```
function myform_handler( $atts ){
    if (isset(@$_REQUEST['submit'])) {
        //Do something
    } else {
        $return = '<form action="" method="post">
                   <input type="text" name="myfield">
                   <input type="submit" name="submit>
                   </form>';
    }
    return $return;
}
add_shortcode( 'myform', 'myform_handler' );
```

Then you can add on any page the following Shortcode, that creates the form (and the form's response):

```
 [myform]
```

Comment: Then I can add it to a static page?

Comment: Exactly. You put that `[myform]` in the static page which will be replaced by the output of `myform_handler`.

Comment: This solution got worked for my need. But I wish there is another way so I do not need to put `html` codes inside of `php` code.

Comment: You can use output buffering. Call `ob_start();`, output your HTML as normal, and then at the end of the fuction call `return ob_get_clean();`.